# can't get jquery banner to work with smooth scroll

Tags: jquery, scrollto

hi i am trying get this http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-banner-rotator-content-slider-carousel/1534434 to work with scrollTo or ANY smooth scrolling plugin but have had 0  luck - the author is also very difficult to communicate with to gain help, but has replied to all emails so far.

he has helped in ascertaining that the banner jquery plugin was conflicting with other jquery plugins, I am now wondering if this was the bestplugin in to buy after all since i cannot get it working with scrollto or any variation.

here is the site i am trying to get it work with: http://sekhu.net/test its a one page website vertical that requires smooth scrolling

can someone advise why this is the case? i am getting no javascript errors.

apologies in advance for the messy code! i want to scroll to each anchor element via the topnav

thanks in advance

code i'm using is as follows in an external file

```
              $('a').click(function(){
              $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
              }, 500);
              return false;
              });
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. What exactly isn't working? What are you expecting to happen.

Comment: it wasnt working at all actually - then i found a script that DOES work with this plugin. thanks for the help regardless guys. as for nsfw, it's just model pictures :P